# Unable to debug Typescript (source) files in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, typescript, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

Ok, I created a basic Angular 2 Typescript project using [5 Min QUICKSTART](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and it's up and running.

My typescript transpiller is configured to create source map:

**tsconfig.js**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

Now I can see the *.ts files in **Chrome** and can debug them as well with no issue. But **Firefox** (and FireFox Developer Edition for that matter) not at all showing the .ts files even though the **"Show Original Sources"** is checked in the debugger options.

[image]

Comment: I see them in FF (47.0) but not in Chrome (51.0.2704.103)

Answer (score 0):

It will work for Firefox if you will specify sourcemap with a full path in compiled js file:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js.map
```

It seams like Firefox can not work with relative paths.

NOTE: Chrome will not work with full path

Answer (score 0):

Hi Saurabh Palatkar,
                Please Follow this below link. It may helpful to fulfill your need. 
            http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/05/27/TypeScript-debugging-in-Visual-Studio-with-IE-Chrome-and-Firefox-using-Source-Maps.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this commented line to your source code

```
//# sourceMappingURL=http://example.com/path/to/your/sourcemap.map
```

Maybe try adding:

```
"typeCheck": true,
```